# xcodebuild archive: set version number and build number

Tags: xcode, archive, xcodebuild

I'm writing a bash script to archive and export my project so I can send it to iTunes Connect. However, the documentation from the command line is a little confusing. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to pass a parameter to the `xcodebuild` command that would set the version number and build number for that archive (similar to how you pass `-scheme MyScheme` when calling xcodebuild). Anyone done something like this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this:

```
/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Set CFBundleVersion $SBUILD_NUMBER" "$PLIST"
/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Set CFBundleShortVersionString $BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION" "$PLIST"
```

with `PLIST` is the path to your `Info.plist`

Comment: Thanks for this. I am really trying to avoid using [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools) as part of my build process for a project. It is just a XCFramework hosted on a repository and I didn't want to pull in all the ruby baggage.

Comment: Plistbuddy comes with macOS. It is not part of fastlane.